# Post-commit Hook Script to append text in modified area

Tags: svn

I have a post commit hook script that will print the newly added lines on the file specified by me in the server,when any new lines are added from the client side and committed.(using svnlook diff command to identify changes)...if i would like to append a line say  "HELLO"  on each modified area of the file on the client side how should i write post-commit hook script....thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** change a revision using a hook. From the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks):

> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in which hook script authors should show restraint: do not modify a commit transaction using hook scripts. While it might be tempting to use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way, those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to surprising and unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired requirements. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful, compliance-minded work habits.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763257/387981